# Been trying to web scrape a blocked website for over a month

Tags: python, csv, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to web scrape this damned website 'https://www.soccerstats.com/' for so long, but it's not working. The website is blocked in my country. I usually open it with a vpn extension. But, on python I couldn't use but a proxy, I tried countless ways to connect to a proxy but nothing changed. Here's my code:

```
import csv
import random
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

csv_file = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer = 'proxies.csv')
all_ips = csv_file['IPs']
all_ports = csv_file['Ports']
proxies_list = [f'{all_ips[i]}:{all_ports[i]}' for i in range(30)]

pick_proxy = random.choice(proxies_list)

prox = Proxy({
 
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'http': f'{pick_proxy}',
    'https': f'{pick_proxy}',
    'httpProxy': f'{pick_proxy}',
    'socksProxy': f'{pick_proxy}',
    'sslProxy': f'{pick_proxy}',
    'socksVersion': 5,
    'noProxy': 'localhost'

})

some_options = Options()
some_options.proxy = prox
some_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={pick_proxy}')
some_options.add_experimental_option(name = 'detach', value = True)

driver = Chrome(options = some_options)
driver.get('https://www.soccerstats.com/')
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name = "theteam"]')
element.send_keys(value = 'Barcelona FC')
element.click()
```

And here's the proxies.csv file:

```
IPs,Ports,Country,Ping,Type,Anonymity Level
180.183.157.159,8080,Thailand,280,HTTPS,High
46.4.96.137,1080,Germany,580,SOCKS5,High
47.91.88.100,1080,Germany “Frankfurt am Main”,260,SOCKS5,High
45.77.56.114,30205,United Kingdom London,320,"SOCKS4, SOCKS5",High
82.196.11.105,1080,Netherlands Amsterdam,580,SOCKS5,High
51.254.69.243,3128,France,440,HTTPS,High
178.62.193.19,1080,Netherlands Amsterdam,580,SOCKS5,High
188.226.141.127,1080,Netherlands Amsterdam,580,SOCKS5,High
217.23.6.40,1080,Netherlands,400,SOCKS5,High
185.153.198.226,32498,Moldova,540,"SOCKS4, SOCKS5",High
81.171.24.199,3128,Netherlands,280,HTTPS,High
5.189.224.84,10000,Russian Federation,560,"SOCKS4, SOCKS5",High
108.61.175.7,31802,United Kingdom London,300,"SOCKS4, SOCKS5",High
176.31.200.104,3128,France,340,HTTPS,High
83.77.118.53,17171,Switzerland Ebikon,400,HTTPS,High
173.192.21.89,80,United States Dallas,520,"HTTP, HTTPS",High
163.172.182.164,3128,France,300,HTTPS,High
163.172.168.124,3128,France,300,HTTPS,High
164.68.105.235,3128,United States “Lake Forest”,320,HTTPS,High
5.199.171.227,3128,Lithuania,300,HTTPS,High
93.171.164.251,8080,Russian Federation Livny,120,HTTPS,High
212.112.97.27,3128,Kyrgyzstan,380,HTTPS,High
51.68.207.81,80,United Kingdom,580,HTTPS,High
91.211.245.176,8080,Lithuania,200 ,HTTPS,High
84.201.254.47,3128,Russian Federation Izhevsk,240,HTTPS,High
95.156.82.35,3128,Russian Federation Ulan-Ude,240 ,"HTTP, HTTPS",High
185.118.141.254,808,Turkey “Magnesia ad Sipylum”,480,"HTTP, HTTPS",High
164.68.98.169,9300,Germany,360,SOCKS5,High
217.113.122.142,3128,Russian Federation Tolyatti,180,HTTPS,High
188.100.212.208,21129,Germany Dormagen,480 ,HTTPS,High
83.77.118.53,17171,Switzerland Ebikon,400,HTTPS,High
83.79.50.233,64527,Switzerland Baar,460,HTTPS,High
```

Note:
The 'chromedriver.exe' is in the same folder. It works well with the other websites.

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of the HTTPS proxies in your list (CSV) are working

Comment: This is not the only csv I work with. It's just one. I suspect something is wrong with the code itself not the proxies.

Comment: But you are pseudo-randomly selecting a proxy so you could very easily be choosing one that doesn't work!

Comment: I tried every proxy randomly, and not. Manually, and non-manually. From multiple sites. Nothing changed. That's why I suspect it's the code is wrong.